# Using an iterator for handing out cards from a deck

Tags: python-3.x, function, iterator

I've written a function which allows for handing out cards to players, using an iterator. I am still not sure that using an iterator is a good idea here. Can you offer another implementation i.e. distribution of cards between players? Or can you correct my function so that it will be more concise?

```
import random


mydeck = [r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'SHDC']

def deal(numhands, n=5, deck=mydeck):
 if numhands*n> len(deck):
    return ('One or more parameters of the function might be incorrect')
 random.shuffle(deck)
 iterator=iter(deck)
 result=[]
 for player in range(numhands):
    interim=[]
    for card in range(n):
        interim.append(next(iterator))
    result.append(interim)
 return result
```

numhands - the number of players

n        - the number of cards in a hand

a deck of 52 cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You might use a list comprehension and slices which is more "Pythonic".
- You might consider using a safe random number generator (`random.SystemRandom()`) to prevent cheating in your game.
- You should treat the global variable as a constant - changing it can cause problems with parallel execution of your code.
- You should raise an exception instead of returning a hard-coded error message.

---

```
'''Card Dealer'''

import random

DECK = [r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'SHDC']

def deal(numhands, handsize=5, deck=DECK):
    '''Returns a list of hands'''
    if numhands*handsize > len(deck):
        raise IndexError("Too many cards requested")
    shuffled = list(deck)
    random.SystemRandom().shuffle(shuffled)
    return [shuffled[i:i+handsize] for i in range(0, numhands*handsize, handsize)]
```

Comment: I like your list comprehension. Thanks, it is much better than my function.